# Integrity constraint/duplicate key on stored proc in php with empty table

Tags: php, stored-procedures, pdo, db2

I'm still stuck on issues with calling a stored procedure in db2 through php.
I got this to finally invoke and get errors to print, but I can't understand why I'm getting these current errors.

The first bit before the while loop is fine, selecting the appropriate data. I then loop on that data, bind the returned rows as parameters and execute a stored procedure call on those parameters. In the catch within my while loop (after printing selected data) I get the error:

`PROC FAILED: SQLSTATE23000: Integrity Constraint violation: -803......Dupicate key value specified`

Now, I do have key contraints set on this table but the odd thing here is I'm calling this procedure on an empty table, so it's impossible it's trying to insert duplicates. Also, if I take the data set from one of the error lines and insert it manually by calling the proc in my IDE it inserts ok.

Is there something else that could cause this error?

```
$sql = "
    SELECT 
        CAST(NUMBER as int) as NUMBER, 
        CAST('Test List' as VARCHAR(50)) as LIST,
        CAST(NAME as int) AS NAME, 
        CAST(GROUPING as varchar(50)) AS GROUPING,
        CAST(DETAIL1 as int) AS DETAIL1,
        CAST(DETAIL2 as int) AS DETAIL2,
        CAST(DETAIL2NAME as varchar(50)) AS DETAIL2NAME, 
        CAST(CATEGORY as varchar(50)) as CATEGORY,
        CAST('None' as varchar(256)) as COMMENTS
    from productTest p
    GROUP BY NUMBER, NAME,GROUPING,DETAIL1,DETAIL2,DETAIL2NAME,CATEGORY
    order by NUMBER
";

try {
    $getRows = $DB2connProd->prepare($sql);
    $numResult = $getRows->execute();

}catch(PDOException $ex) {
    $OrdSlctError = "ORDER SELECT FAILED!: " .$ex->getMessage();
    print_r($OrdSlctError);
}


while ($orderRow = $getRows->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    print_r($orderRow);

    $proc = "CALL TEST . TEST_INSERT(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, DEFAULT, DEFAULT)";

    try{

        $callProc = $DB2connProd->prepare($proc);

        $callProc->bindParam(1, $orderRow["NUMBER"], PDO::PARAM_INT, 10);
        $callProc->bindParam(2, $orderRow["LIST"], PDO::PARAM_STR, 50);
        $callProc->bindParam(3, $orderRow["NAME"], PDO::PARAM_INT, 10);
        $callProc->bindParam(4, $orderRow["GROUPING"], PDO::PARAM_STR,50);
        $callProc->bindParam(5, $orderRow["DETAIL1"], PDO::PARAM_INT, 10);
        $callProc->bindParam(6, $orderRow["DETAIL2"], PDO::PARAM_INT, 10);
        $callProc->bindParam(7, $orderRow["DETAIL2NAME"], PDO::PARAM_STR, 50);
        $callProc->bindParam(8, $orderRow["CATEGORY"], PDO::PARAM_STR, 50);
        $callProc->bindParam(9, $orderRow["COMMENTS"], PDO::PARAM_STR, 256);

        $callProc->execute();

        print_r($callProc);

    }catch(PDOException $ex){

        echo "PROC FAILED!: " .$ex->getMessage();

    }
}
```

Comment: If the CALL statement (as distinct from the parameter values) to the sproc is not changing each iteration, then it's an error to prepare it each time.   You are the only person who can tell if the bound parameters match exactly the routine-signature.  The -803 will be returned if the table being inserted is in a different schema than what you think, or if the unique-column(s) known only to you are not in fact unique.  This should be simple to debug.

Comment: You;re correct, it looks like I should have removed the '10' from my INT declarations